# using the digits 1,2,3,4 and 5, how many 3 digit numbers if the three digits can be formed if the first digit must be two and

Tags: math-software

repetition of the digits is allowed? I just don't understand this question. Can you use this type of question in excel?

Answer (score 1):

Fix the first 2 digits by picking one among $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ so this step can be done in 5 different ways. Then choose the third number from the same set (since repitition is allowed). So again this can be done in 5 different ways. So total ways would be 5*5 = 25.